# Unable to Assign Value to Char Variable in below Code?

Tags: c

Puzzeled with this C program , This program is not asking for CHOICE as INPUT when i execute in this order but if I put Integer Input (inputNum) statement after choice asking choice input is working but then Integer Input is not taking input Value

```
      int main()
      {  int inputNum;   char choice='A';

          printf("Please enter number : ");
          scanf("%d",&inputNum);

          printf("\nEnter (N/n) to STOP ADDING : ");
          scanf("%c",&choice);
          printf("\nChoice is : %c\n",choice);

          return 0;
       }
```

Comment: change to `scanf(" %c",&choice);`

Comment: Adding the space as suggested by @BLUEPIXY is the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's going on.

```
      printf("Please enter number : ");
      scanf("%d",&inputNum);
```

When this runs, you are prompted to enter a number, and then of course *you hit return* to flush the input buffer.  That leaves a `\n` (newline) character in there, which gets read by:

```
     printf("\nEnter (N/n) to STOP ADDING : ");
     scanf("%c",&choice);
```

So the program goes `Choice is :` and leaves a blank line -- that's the `\n` that got put into `choice`.

One solution is to use;

```
scanf("%*c%c", &choice);
```

The `*` tells `scanf()` to discard the field, in this case, the newline remaining from the last input.

> if I put Integer Input (inputNum) statement after choice asking choice input is working

It's important to note that the issue with the newline won't affect `%d` scans, because these *skip leading whitespace*.  So if you ask for two integers in your program instead of an int and a char, it works without the need to manually skip the newline.  The same logic applies to most kinds of input, as per a statement from the ISO C 99 Draft Standard repeated in the [POSIX man page for fscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html):

> Input white-space characters (as specified by isspace) shall be
>   skipped, unless the conversion specification includes a [, c, C, or n
>   conversion specifier.

That "unless" applies of course to `%c`.

Comment: Didn't even know about that last paragraph. Good answer.

Comment: Very good answer .It solved my problem and I learned something important

Comment: You're welcome :)  If this satisfies the question, tick the big checkmark at the top of the answer to show the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

The return character (pressed to validate your first input) is still present in the standard input buffer.

You can solve your issue by adding `getchar();` after your first `scant`, as it will consume the stray `\n` of the buffer, leaving it empty for your next input.